# No water in the region

Tags: simcity-4

When I started the game there was a lot of water in my region, but now when I switched to other cities where there was a water in valleys. The water was just absent.

I don't understand where the water disappeared?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this could have been an side-effect of a mod.

You have some mods installed, which may remove the water in order to build bridges and something like that.

Comment: SC4 has no weather at all, except disasters

Comment: Are your right. Sim City 4 has no rain. It was the older ones who have it. I remove the second point, as it is not available in SimCity 4